# Print value using Jquery file

Tags: jquery, function, printing, trygetvalue

I have a function in my jQuery file:

```js
function updateHTML(blocks) {
  var data   = getData(blocks),
      price  = formatPrice(data.price),
      hourly = formatCents(data.hourly),
      p      = $.priceSlider.settings;

  $(p.processor_id).text(data.processor + ' GHZ');
  $(p.ram_id).text(data.ram + ' GB');
  $(p.price_id).text('$' + price);
  $(p.storage_id).text(data.storage + ' GB');
  $(p.bandwidth_id).text(data.bandwidth + ' GB');
  $(p.blocks_id).attr('class', 'block_' + data.blocks);
  $(p.hourly_price_id).text('$' + hourly + '/hr');
}
```

I have to print the value contain in the last line(

```
$(p.hourly_price_id).text('$' + hourly + '/hr');
```

on the index page. how can i do this?

Comment: [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: I think you problem is aboout '/hr', because / is special character, so you should write it like this://hr

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `$(p.hourly_price_id).text('$' + hourly + '/hr');` should be `$('p.hourly_price_id').text('$' + hourly + '/hr');` as jQuery selector requires quotes. If the `p` tag on the page already have the class `hourly_price_id`, the change is done. If not, you can append such an element to wherever you like with `apendTo` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)) or `append` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/)) depending on your likings.

Also, if you want a unique ID for the paragraph tag, use `<p id="hourly_price">` and jQuery selector `$('p#hourly_price')`.